# Returning as bool value from sql server to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I had written query where my result creating a column. That created column needs to come as a bool to sql server.

```
SELECT *,case 

            when(A.EndDt<getdate())

            then 0

            else 1 

        end as CheckStatus

            FROM benOpenEnrollment A WHERE   A.BenefitClassID=
   @BenefitClassID ORDER BY A.StartDt
```

The above query CheckStatus I need as a bool value when it comes to front end from dr.
My fron end code that which I already written as follows :

```
if (!dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("CheckStatus")))
 {
     objElectBenefits.CheckStatus =  
                                dr.GetBoolean(dr.GetOrdinal("CheckStatus"));
  }
```

I'm getting the exception as , "Specified cast is not valid.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the result to `Datatype` `BIT` and try it,

```
SELECT *,CAST((case 
            when(A.EndDt<getdate())
            then 0
            else 1 
        end) AS bit) as CheckStatus
FROM benOpenEnrollment A 
WHERE A.BenefitClassID=   @BenefitClassID 
ORDER BY A.StartDt
```